# Unit testing React component that includes MathJax

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, mathjax

I'm looking for a way to unit test a React component that involves MathJax. Currently, my only means of getting MathJax to work in actual code is through the script tag:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'></script>
```

This works fine in the actual code, but the testing environment is different. I've tried adding the above to the initial creation of JSDOM:

```
const dom = new JSDOM(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'></script>
  </body>
</html>
`);
```

But it produces:

> ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined.

I've tried `import MathJax from 'mathjax';` from the NPM module, but this of course does not work as MathJax was not designed to work from an import.

I've also tried adding the MathJax [single file](https://github.com/pkra/MathJax-single-file) versions, but my code runs in strict mode, which errors trying to implement them due to their use of `arguments.callee`, etc.

So I'm at a loss as to how to unit test a component that has MathJax involved.

Here is the test:

```
describe('test', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TheComponent {...props} />); // this seems to be where the problem originates
  });
});
```

> ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined.

And this is the component:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  MathJax.Hub.Config(...
}

componentDidMount () {
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(...
}

componentDidUpdate () {
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(...
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to test MathJax itself in your unit tests, or do you just want to test the React Component? If you're fine with stubbing out MathJax, you can just add some stubs into the global scope. https://jaketrent.com/post/testing-react-with-jsdom/

Comment: Ah, right. I had forgotten about stubbing. Thanks. I think this should solve the issue. I'll have to try it out now.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to mock MathJax as I'm just testing the React Component. The problem is that the shallow rendering of the component errors when it finds that there is no reference to MathJax in the component file. (It resides in the `<script>` tag before the `</body>`.

Comment: Right, and looking at MathJax, it looks like it injects itself into the global scope. So if you do something like global.MathJax = {Hub: {...}} with your jsdom setup, your shallowing rendering should be able to find it. I'm not familiar with MathJax specifically, so it may be doing something funky I'm not aware of.

Comment: @NickWyman I'm slightly beating myself up over this. I did exactly what you have suggested for other items that required being set up as a global variable, but it didn't occur to me to do it here. Thanks! This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a MathJax-React lib that might help. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax

This should allow you to test your "MathJax" components like all your other react components.

```
const tex = `\frac{3}{4}`

module.exports = () => {
  return (
    <MathJax.Provider>
      <MathJax.Node formula={tex} />
    </MathJax.Provider>
  );
}
```